# How to create an executable program from netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable

I have just finished developing a small java application on Netbeans IDE. I am curious as to how I can convert that into an executable program from netbeans. So that there would be a short cut icon which when double clicked loads all classes and runs the main function with all relevant jar files also compiled. i.e. JCalender, JTatto, aswell as sqlitejdbc.jar. all of which are in a directory of the project.

Comment: Did you try any of the answers from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Launch4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/), a Java program that can turn your `.jar` file into a standard Windows Executable `.exe` file while building all references into that single file.